# silverlight control size

Tags: silverlight, controls

The control that I have built is of size 30x30. however, when the control is rendered, it takes up most of the space on the browser? Why is that so?

Any way to reduce the size to what is desired?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give us some code so we can tell you what the issue is.

Comment: I had set the objects height and width to 500!! changed that to 30 and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your *object* tag's width and height attributes.

```
<object width="300" height="300"
    data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
    <param name="source" value="..."/>
</object>
```